# How to choose between a count model and spatial error model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit, negative-binomial-distribution, spatial

I have a dataset with spatial grid cells. After performing some spatial diagnostics (Moran's I, LaGrange multiplier tests), it seems that there is spatial dependency in the form of spatial error, so a spatial error model seemed fitting. However, my dependent variable is a count variable and is quite skewed (the standard deviation is much higher than the mean). From what I have gathered this violates the assumptions of the spatial error model (which assumes more continuous data) and also seems to lead to heteroskedasticity, biasing the results.

An alternative could be to run a negative binomial model, which seems to fit the data better but leaves out the spatial dependencies, also biasing the results. I know there are some ways to perform spatial count models, but these seem to complex to grasp for me at this stage (or to difficult to implement in R).

My question is: how do I choose between these two evils; unfortunately the results are quite different. Is there a good way to compare goodness-of-fit? The AIC and Log Likelihood are much better for the negative binomial model whereas the RMSE of the spatial model is better but I am not sure if I can compare either those metrics across the models.

Comment: For an example of doing both, check the "Extra Notes 2" part of the following website: https://apwheele.github.io/Class_CrimeMapping/08_Tutorial_R_SpatRegression.html